# How to center the items in my menu while having 100% width background

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I am working on a website: http://homegym.sg/index.php/

Have used jquery to create an effect such that when the user scroll down, a black menu will appear at the top of the screen. However i have been trying alot of ways but it is not able to show as what i wanted.

I wanted to have the background of the menu fill 100% width of the screen. The middle part of my screen is fixed width (960px) but when the user screen is more than 960px the background will expand to fill the side.

For my website background it is doing that, but for the menu background, the only closest effect i get is having the background fill the entire width of the screen, but with the contents align to the left (what i wanted is center alignment).

My div for the menu is #menu, css are found is menu.css

Here some part of the code:

```
  #menu {

    width: 100%;
    z-index:888; 
    display:none; 
    position:fixed; 
    top:0 ;
    left: 0;
}

ul.topnav {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 50px;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    background: #222;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background: url(../images/css_menu/topnav_bg.gif) repeat-x;

}
```

Comment: I'm having hard time to understand what is the problem. Do you simply want the background to be 100% in width and the content to be center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `width` of the `div#menu` should be `100%` and this `div` gets the `background`.
To center the `ul.topnav` it needs the real `width` (of all `li`s) and `margin auto`.

Change your css defintions to:

```
#menu {
    background: url("../images/css_menu/topnav_bg.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 888;
}

ul.topnav {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 802px;
}
```

Comment: Tried and it work! Thanks alot. I have more experience with java, thus when it comes to css and javascript, is mostly based on trial and error and referencing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test on your page directly because you have JavaScript parse errors, and I don't feel like copying your code to JSFiddle at this point in time but I can give a suggestion.  Try setting the horizontal margin of your menu to auto:

```
div#menu {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

or, more pedantically:

```
div#menu {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: If the `#menu` is 100% in width, then what use does the `margin: 0px auto;` have?

Comment: i have tried setting the margins to auto but it doesn't work. May i know which error are you referring to? I will try to fix it.

Comment: Oops, should have been ul.topnav getting the auto margin.  I made an error.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked it out, and the problem is the float element and margins. Try with this css properties (I've changed them to absolute paths for my local testing):

```
#menu {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 888;
    background: url(http://homegym.sg/skin/frontend/default/electronics01-black/images/css_menu/topnav_bg.gif) repeat-x;
}

ul.topnav {
    width: 820px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 50px;
    float: none;
    text-align: left;
    background: #222;
    font-size: 1.2em;   
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.topnav li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
    position: relative; /*--Declare X and Y axis base for sub navigation--*/
    background: url(http://homegym.sg/skin/frontend/default/electronics01-black/images/css_menu/main-delimiter.png) 95% 4px no-repeat;
}
```

By the way, nice website!

Comment: Thanks for your ans. However when i tried your method, i am unable to see the menu text and the dropdown are all on the left side instead of their respective place. However i still appreciate your help! Bought this template and there's alot of things which i don't like, thus spent quite a long time tweaking it :)